# Representation of enums

Tags: enums, implementation, multiple-languages

How do enums work 'behind the scenes' in programming languages? I am guessing that each language has a different way of representing these datatypes.

In java you can use the == operator, for example:

```
public class TestEnum {
   private enum Test {
      foo, bar
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Test.foo == Test.foo); // returns true
   }
}
```

Is an enum type converted to a primitive during the ==? Or is the enum value a Singleton? Does C# leverage enums in the same manner as java? Are database enum types treated differently compared to programming languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java `enum`s make use of a *lot* of tricks to still be objects but work with `==`. The original [typesafe enum pattern](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/shiftintojava/page1.html#replaceenums) (see also *Effective Java*) can provide some insight, but the [Enum.java source](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/Enum.java.htm) will show you exactly how they do it now.

Answer (score 1):

An enum type in Java is actually a special compiler-generated class rather than an arithmetic type: enum values behave as global pre-generated instances in order to compare references in place of `equals`.

You can verify it disassembling a .class file:

```
  Code:
    0:   getstatic       #2; //Field YourEnum.BAR:LYourEnum;
    3:   getstatic       #3; //Field YourEnum.FOO:LYourEnum;
    6:   if_acmpne       17
```

it should roughly equivalent to the following Java code:

```
enum YourEnum {
    FOO,
    BAR
}

// ...
if (YourEnum.BAR == YourEnum.FOO)
```

For the sake of simplicity you can think it as a special case of **string interning**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that most languages convert enums into `int` behind the scenes - although that certainly isn't requirement.

For example - in your example above it is certainly possible that the compiler realizes that the two values are equal without ever converting them to some intermediate representation and just emits a `true` value.

Answer (score 0):

.Net language represent them in form of integers. 
If you do

If 1 == foo , this should return true

What I would usually to be easier to understand is this :

```
public enum Test
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
end enum
```

Give it a try, change the 1 and 2 with strings. This should throw you a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I would think enums are simply const integers.

so you have

```
const int foo = 0;
const int bar = 1;
```

and so on with the compiler adding the namespace 'Test' to them